# Metolar XR after Lis ASD surgery

Tags: cardiology, prescription, congenital, post-surgical, atrial-septal-defect-asd

I am 33 and had an LIS, ASD closure,everything went well, however my doctor suggested me to be on Metolar XR 25mg for a year.

I am worried since I had no hypertension or rhythmic disturbance but had high cholesterol before surgery. I worried if Metolar can increase the cholesterol level?

Comment: I have went ahead and tweaked your question a bit. If you are not satisfied by my edit, please rollback the edit.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metoprolol#Adverse_effects

No listed effects on cholesterol. Make sure you have a balanced, healthy diet and take your medication recommended by your doctor. If still in doubt, consult a separate independent physician.

On prescription:

> Metoprolol is used for a number of conditions, including hypertension,
>   angina, acute myocardial infarction, supraventricular tachycardia,
>   ventricular tachycardia, congestive heart failure, and prevention of
>   migraine headaches. Treatment of heart failure Vasovagal
>   syncope. Adjunct in treatment of hyperthyroidism Long QT
>   syndrome, especially for patients with asthma, as metoprolol's β1
>   selectivity tends to interfere less with asthma drugs, which are often
>   β2-adrenergic receptor-agonist drugs. Prevention of
>   relapse into atrial fibrillation (controlled-release/extended-release
>   form)
>
> Due to its selectivity in blocking the beta1 receptors in the heart,
>   metoprolol is also prescribed for off-label use in performance
>   anxiety, social anxiety disorder, and other anxiety disorders.